# Managing multiple dependency versions with OSGI/Maven

Tags: java, maven, osgi, dependency-management

I've got a Maven build for an OSGI project I'm working on.  I'd like to use some functionality from Google's guava-osgi library, version 11.0.1.

One of the projects I'm depending on has a dependency on guava-osgi, version 10.0.0.  I know that having multiple versions for a particular dependency is feasible, but I'm having a little trouble with it.

Specifying the dependency on 11.0.1 in my project's pom compiles just fine, but when I run my unit tests, Java's pulling in version 10.0.0, which results in a runtime error.  Specifically, one of the classes in 11.0.1 has the same name as an interface in 10.0.0, so Java barfs when I try to instantiate it.

Is there a way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check dependency tree with [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/): `mvn dependency:tree`
2. Find all dependencies that are active in test scope with `guava-osgi:10.0.0` version
3. Exclude `guava-osgi:10.0.0` from test scope

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>dep1-groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>dep1-artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>dep1-version</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.guava-osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-osgi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
...
```

Comment: Is this in addition to the dependency I've already set up on dep1?  I need dep1 beyond the 'test' scope.

Comment: it's better to exclude 10.0.0 version from all dependencies. check mvn dependency:tree for more details.

Comment: My question is why you're providing "<scope>test</scope>"  Also, I'm not sure if 10.0.0 is compatible with 11.0.1.  I'd like them to run side-by-side, with my project using 11.0.1 and my dependency using 10.0.0.

Comment: <scope>test</scope> - is a scope for maven unit tests. if you decide to use 11.0.1 version you have to exclude the old version from you compile and test scope.

Comment: But there's no guarantee that my dependency will just work with 11.0.1 if it depends on 10.0.0.  Is there a way to use both versions at the same time and have the imports from my project pull in 11.0.1 while having the imports from the dependency pull in 10.0.0?

Comment: I suggest you to avoid any version mixes. If you like to use both version you have to cover all functionality with unit tests to be sure that your code does not have any problems with your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to exclude the 10.0.0 version from the 'project i depend on'

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>project i depend on</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.guava-osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-osgi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
...
```

Comment: dang. Perhaps another dependency is also using the 10.0.0 version?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a OSGi based environment you can easily specify the needed guava version using the bundle plugin. But, it's important to understand that at compile-time, and at unit testing time (ie. within Maven), it doesn't know/care about the OSGi environment you created. So, you have to use some trick as mentioned in other answers. I haven't tested those though.